# Why do the if statements work, but NOT the else statements?

Tags: python, if-statement, nameerror

All if statements work, but the else statements in the first two if/else blocks return the following error? Can someone please tell me why this is?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 36, in <module>
    if swim_or_wait.lower() == "wait":
NameError: name 'swim_or_wait' is not defined
```

code

```
left_or_right = input("Choose which way you want to go. Left or right? ")

if left_or_right.lower() == "left":
  swim_or_wait = input("Do you want to swim or wait? ")
else:
    print("Wrong way. You fell into a hole. Game over.")

if swim_or_wait.lower() == "wait":
  which_door = input("Choose which door you want to go through? Red, blue, or yellow? ")
else:
  print("You've been attacked by a trout. Game Over.")

if which_door.lower() == "red":
  print("Burned by fire. Game Over.")
elif which_door.lower() == "blue":
  print("Eaten by beasts. Game Over.")
elif which_door.lower() == "yellow":
  print("Congratulations!!! The game is yours. You Win!")
else:
  print("Wrong door. Game Over.")`your text
```

Comment: You never assigned `swim_or_wait` or `which_door` in the else statements, which is why the error tells you that the name is not defined.

Comment: swim_or_wait only comes into existence when left_or_right == 'left'

Comment: You only define `swim_or_wait` inside of the `if` block and not the `else` block. Python executes only certain lines of code, and so if it follows the `else` code, it never sees that `swim_or_wait` is defined.

Comment: The Pythonic way to fix this is usually to put `swim_or_wait = None` or something similar just above your `if` statement so that `swim_or_wait` is defined.

Comment: And this has nothing to do with _else part is not working_....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`swim_or_wait` is only ever defined in the first if statement. If that first if statement doesn't trigger, then this variable does not exist. You essentially have a logic error as really you need to have this second if statement nested (ugh, there are better more elegant ways of doing this but this will suffice for a homework project that this sounds like).

*Forgive my formatting below on the indentations.*

Par Example:

```py
left_or_right = input("Choose which way you want to go. Left or right? ")

if left_or_right.lower() == "left":
    swim_or_wait = input("Do you want to swim or wait? ")
    if swim_or_wait.lower() == "wait":
        which_door = input(
            "Choose which door you want to go through? Red, blue, or yellow?"
        )
        ## You'd be better with a case switch here
        if which_door.lower() == "red":
            print("Burned by fire. Game Over.")
        elif which_door.lower() == "blue":
            print("Eaten by beasts. Game Over.")
        elif which_door.lower() == "yellow":
            print("Congratulations!!! The game is yours. You Win!")
        else:
            print("Wrong door. Game Over.")
    else:
        print("You've been attacked by a trout. Game Over.")
else:
    print("Wrong way. You fell into a hole. Game over.")
```